# Adding and Deploying Multiple solutions in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, deployment, solution-package

I have got around 10's of webpart solutions that I need to add and then deploy to all web applications, I would prefer if someone can share easiest way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to bundle them all into a single solution as there is no reason for each web part to be in it's own solution, aside from development silos.

Beyond that, you are likely looking at writing a very large batch file / powershell script that retracts the features, retracts the solutions, deletes the solutions, then adds the solutions, redeploys them and then activates the features on their respective web applications.  The specifics of this will vary with the farm and with each solution but you are basically looking at a lot of this:

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature ...
stsadm -o retractsolution ...
stsadm -o deletesolution ...
stsadm -o addsolution ...
stsadm -o deploysolution ...
stsadm -o activatefeature ...
```

Comment: Because is SharePoint 2007, just make sure you prepare yourself if you plan to use Powershell, see here http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/09/03/preparing-powershell-for-sharepoint-and-moss-2007/

Comment: @C.Marius Agreed.  Everyone who is doing anything administrative with SharePoint really should be getting comfortable with PowerShell.  The fact that PowerShell simply rocks is an added benefit :)

Comment: If you are new to PowerShell and SharePoint i have found the builder tool quite handy: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/TechNet/en-us/Office/media/WindowsPowerShell/WindowsPowerShellCommandBuilder.html

Comment: Of course, if you don't have support for PowerShell, try creating a big batch file (.bat) that performs all the deployment.

Comment: @DaveWise thanks for your answer but All of these solutions already got several webparts in them and they are all categorized so bundling solutions will make things complicated as well as hard to debug so I don't think it will best practice to bundle them up, I thought about power shell script but was wondering if someone knew any utility that could be helpful and fasten things up I wasn't aware of, if not then I will try to use Power Shell or creating a batch file.

Comment: The problem you will have automating this is that each WSP likely has unique deployment requirements and most certainly have unique features that need to be activated.  Most likely, you will end up with an enormous script to do this all.  FWIW, debugging a large integrated solution is pretty much the same as debugging a small solution as you go through the same motions in either case.  However, since these are already established and deployed solutions, then integrating them would possibly bring unwanted complications.